# Why is the symlink I created inside an application container to allow for external storage not working?

Tags: macos, podcasts, symlink

I was trying to get around Vemedio's Instacast limitation on storage location by symlinking (`ln -s`) the Episodes folder in `~Library/Containers/com.vemedio.osx.Instacast/Data/Documents/Instacast` to another location on another drive (which is actually internal in my Mac Pro for what it is worth...). I am wondering if Apple's sandboxing is preventing this to work... Once I open Instacast, none of the previously downloaded episodes are marked as available locally and if I try to redownload one, it seems to download the file in the background but never makes it available... Any idea?

Comment: what symlink command path are you using for the other drive exactly (anonymize if you must but include important stuff)?

Comment: `ln -s /Volumes/BigOne/Podcasts/Episodes` while I am in `/Users/kheldar/Library/Containers/com.vemedio.osx.Instacast/Data/Documents/Instacast`

Comment: Have you tried killing the link and simply creating an alias in finder instead?  Some programs only resolve one or the other depending on implementation.

Comment: After you make the link (but before launching Instacast), does the link work? That is, if you put a text file in the folder, can you see it in both places?

Comment: Yes the link works I can cd into the link and I can copy things from one to the other. However, Instacast does not see any of the linked files, which tells me it is looking for a specific file ID which I deleted when I changed the folder into a symlink... WHat do you think?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, symlinking *a part of* the folder inside of the `Containers` folder doesn't work. If you want to symlink, you have to symlink the **whole** folder, i.e. com.vemedio.osx.Instacast

On OS X versions that support sandboxed apps (beginning from Lion), it's sometimes impossible to symlink a sandboxed app application support files to other partition, at least, an inner portion of the folder structure.

https://gist.github.com/certainlyakey/e6729864ba3fe73f9cc1:

> For example, Airmail is a sandboxed email client. I'd like to move its
> settings and email db to another partition by symlinking it, but it
> doesn't work with the app if I symlink an inner folder of its library
> container:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Library/Containers/it.bloop.airmail.beta7/Data/Library/Application\ Support/
> ln -s /Volumes/doxx/sys/Airmail Airmail
> ```
>
> The solution is to symlink the whole container:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Library/Containers/
> ln -s /Volumes/doxx/sys/Airmail/it.bloop.airmail it.bloop.airmail
> ```