# How to create a custom readable symlink out of a sandboxed container?

Tags: macos, permission, symlink, library

How do I create a **readable** symlink from within a `~/Library/Containers/.../Data/` app folder to a file outside?

It seems that due to the macOS sandboxing mechanism, this doesn't work out of the box. That is, I can create a symlink fine, but the app I use won't be allowed to read the symlinked file.

**Notes:**

- My intent is to customize the setup of my own machine. I'm not an app developer.
- Editing the file `Container.plist` within `~/Library/Containers/.../` might help. So far, I've not had success yet.
- Personal use case: being able to open an app from two different user accounts on the same machine and share the same app-database.

Answer (score 1):

## Unlikely to be Possible

I suspect that if this were possible with a symlink, Apple would consider it a serious security flaw.

That said, see [Why is the symlink I created inside an application container to allow for external storage not working?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99174) for possible solutions.

Sandboxed applications can only read the contents their containers, some global locations, and the locations explicitly granted to them by the user – via the Powerbox mechanism.

See [Powerbox and File System Access Outside of Your Container](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW17):

> Your sandboxed app can access file system locations outside of its container in the following three ways:
>
> - At the specific direction of the user
> - By using entitlements for specific file-system locations (described in > - Entitlements and System Resource Access)
> - When the file system location is in certain directories that are world readable

Given the list above, you *may* be able to extend the entitlements for the application to include your specific location and then resign the application.

### Bypass the Problem

Alternatively, consider stripping the application of its sandboxing entitlement. You could try [ad-hoc resigning](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288291) the application and omit the entitlements entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your research. Much appreciated. As for the solution outlined in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99174 – in my case, symlinking the entire container leads to obstacles if two different users (on the same machine) want to open the app.